# Disable adb force-stop in the app

Tags: android

I am trying to disable force stop of the android app I am writing. The "force stop" is disabled in the settings. I was expecting to see the same behavior using adb, but I can kill my app if I send a force-stop command using adb.

Is there any way this can be disabled in my app? Essentially, the behavior should be the same in both cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your app cannot control that. The app process is killed by the OS, you cannot prevent this.